# Как правильно освободить память?

Tags: c++

Вот задача:

"Заполняющий конструктор принимает число и символ, и создает строку с заданным количеством повторений переданного символа. Условия налагаемые на реализацию конструктора те же самые (в поле size размер без учета завершающего 0 символа, в поле str C-style строка, т.е. с завершающим 0 символом). Кроме конструктора в этой задаче вам нужно также реализовать и деструктор, который освободит выделенную память. "

У меня почему то зависает во время выполнения и соответственно не принимается проверяющей системой. 
Не могли бы вы объяснить почему?

Спасибо!

```
#include <cstddef> // size_t
#include <cstring> // strlen, strcpy

struct String {
        String(size_t n, char c)
    :size(n), str(new char [size+1]){
        str[size] = '\0';
          //memset(str, c, n);
        char *tmp = str;
        while(*tmp != '\0'){
            *tmp = c;
            tmp++;
        }
     }

    ~String(){
        delete [] str;
    }

    size_t size;
    char *str;
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас неправильное условие цикла в конструкторе: если по воле случая в выделенном буфере окажутся нули, то буфер не будет заполнен нужным символом полностью. Лучше воспользоваться обычным циклом for с индексированием от 0 до size.

Зависать исходный цикл по идее не должен, но лучше проверить под отладчиком, почему цикл не останавливается.

Самый надежный вариант - воспользоваться memset, если это не запрещено заданием.

С деструктором у вас все в порядке, зависать там нечему.